# MongoDB get value of the key by using the value of the variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection named `Apprentices` looks like this:

```
{
"_id": "BCKnMu5ixBFJys6G9",
"skills": {
    "apGit": true,
    "apCPlus": false,
    "apCSharp": false,
    "apC": false,
    "apJava": false,
    "apJavaScript": false,
    "apMetor": false,
    "apSQL": false,
    "apMongoDB": false,
    "apPHP": false,
    "apPython": false,
    "apHTML": false,
    "apJQuery": false,
    "apiOS": false,
    "apAndroid": false,
    "apRuby": false,
    "apRubyOnRails": false,
    "apNet": false,
    "apSVN": false,
    "apAPI": false,
    "apDevOps": false,
    "apCLI": false,
    "apVM": false,
    "apLinux": false,
    "apOther": false
},
"userID": "8bTuAAZYbu7Xb3ssX"
}
```

and I want to get the specific value of the skills.

With:
    `let user = Apprentices.findOne({'userID' : Meteor.userId()});`

I can get `user.skills.apGit`  is true.

But if I want to use a variable like

`let n = 'apGit'`

`user.skills.n` will be error.

My question is How can I get the value of the `apGit` by using `n`???

Comment: Have you tried `user.skills["apGit"]` or `user.skills[n]`?

Comment: user.skills[n] works for me. Thanks a lot!